# How to use PHP in a html5 setting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, html

In my HTML5 Page I have content container in the article section. One of the pages is PHP and it is breaking my css. I am also having trouble getting the redirects to work correctly what is a better method for doing this here.
Here is the page.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>ACTS</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="../images/template/icon.png?v=1" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="../images/template/startup_landscape.jpg?v=1" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="../images/template/startup_portrait.jpg?v=1" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="includes/acts.css?v=1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">  </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/Iscroll4/iscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../includes/acts.js?v=1"></script>
   </head>
    <body>
    <div class="page">
    <footer></footer>
    <article>
        <div class"content_container">
            <div class="content_loading_container"></div>
    </article>
    <header></header>
    <img class="banner_logo" src="images/template/logo.png?v=1" />
    <img class="banner_acts" src="images/template/ACTS_banner.png?v=1" />
    <img class="fire_clay" src="images/template/home_fire_clay.png?v=1" width="201" height="121" />
    <img class="fire_blue" src="images/template/fire_blue.png?v=1" width="169" height="131" />
    <img class="fire_black" src="images/template/fire_black.png?v=1" width="157" height="129" />
    <img class="fire_orange" src="images/template/fire_orange.png?v=1" width="420" height="440" />
    <nav>
        <a data-file="home.php?v=1">Home</a>
        <a data-file="Tracker.php?v=1">tracker</a>
        <a data-file="reports.php?v=1">Gallery</a>
        <a data-file="contact_us.html?v=1">Contact Us</a>
    </nav>
    </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

PHP page:

```
<?php require_once("includes/tlsession.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/actsconnection.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php

    include_once("includes/form_functions.php");

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
        $errors = array();

        $required_fields = array('username', 'password');
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_required_fields($required_fields, $_POST));

        $fields_with_lengths = array('username' => 30, 'password' => 30);
        $errors = array_merge($errors, check_max_field_lengths($fields_with_lengths, $_POST));

        $username = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['username']));
        $password = trim(mysql_prep($_POST['password']));
        $hashed_password = sha1($password);


        if ( empty($errors) ) {
                        $query = "SELECT id, username ";
            $query .= "FROM users ";
            $query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
            $query .= "AND hashed_password = '{$hashed_password}' ";
            $query .= "LIMIT 1";
            $result_set = mysql_query($query);
            confirm_query($result_set);
            if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
                $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
                $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];

                redirect_to("actstracker.php");
            } else {
                $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.<br />
                    SELF DESTRUCT INITIATED.";
            }
        } else {
            if (count($errors) == 1) {
                $message = "There was 1 error in the form.";
            } else {
                $message = "There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
            }
        }

    } else { // Form has not been submitted.
        if (isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] == 1) {
            $message = "You are now logged out.";
        } 
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
    }
?>
<body>
<h2>Login</h2>
<?php if (!empty($message)) {echo "<p class=\"message\">" . $message . "</p>";} ?>
<?php if (!empty($errors)) { display_errors($errors); } ?>
<div class="page">
<footer></footer>
<article>
    <form action="team-lead-login.php" method="post">
            <table>
            <tr>

            <td>Team Lead:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($username); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

            <a href="tllogout.php">Logout </a>
</article>
<header></header>
<nav></nav>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: PHP shouldn't be affecting your css. Your invalid HTML will, however.

Comment: ok What invalid html are you speaking of?

Comment: the code you've pasted has broken HTML at the top - a `{` plus duplicated `<html>` and `<head>` tags before the doctype, and a `}` at the end. All of this is invalid and will cause rendering issues.

Comment: why do you have <html> and <head> and why <!DOCTYPE HTML> is not at first line?

Comment: Why do you have two `<html>`  and `<head>` at the start? What is the purpose of those `{` and `}` at the start and end?

Comment: #WTF is this? `<html>
<head>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>`

Comment: also not closing the <div class"content_container"> div inside the <article> tags

Comment: @jcho360 that is HTML6 declaration :D

Comment: the {} are a mistake they are not in the original document. I mistakenly added them here. sorry. the extra <head> is also not in the original document. I accidentally added that when pasting it here. once again sorry.

Comment: @jrad, edit your question and put your real HTML then.

Comment: Please edit your post to correct the mistakes so we can go on and try to see what your issue is.

Also you say it breaks your CSS.  How?  Show us what part of your CSS breaks?  Does the entire site lose styling, or just a particular area, if so what area???  Need details.

Comment: Ok let me remark this I have this page working I just saw (thanks to all the **@%&* remarks) I added one of my original pages before I worked the kinks out. I originally had html pages in the container, but am now putting in PHP pages for login and dynamic reasons. however when I add the PHP replacement pages the sight goes to crap. Thanks for all the crap remarks.

Comment: @jrad, changing a href links from html page to php would not affect your css. so you got some other problem. Btw sometimes using html validator like [w3c](http://validator.w3.org/) could help you to see if HTML is broken.

Comment: Their not crap remarks, they are valid points.  You still have a syntax error, which I detailed for you in an answer below, this alone could cause some rendering issues.  When you say the site goes to crap, HOW does it goto crap?  We can't give you an accurate prediction as to what is going on without knowing precisely what is breaking.

Comment: the original I have the png files zooming in on the home page, but when the php. is added the png files start the process and seem to be repelled by the container. Thanks Michael for not being a prick.

Comment: Do you have a live version of this site that I can see this issue?  The PHP you are adding are the .PHP files down at the bottom of the file?

Comment: validator found 11 error on your code, first one is: <div class"content_container">, missing = after class.

Comment: The php is a simple login and submission form. I am working on a local host at this point. I think the problem might be that I have a single page submission form, I might need to go to a HTML5 form with a separate php submission page. Call me lazy for not wanting to do it over again.

Comment: Is it inline PHP?  Like you're adding the PHP into the HTML above?  If so, did you rename the file above from .html to .php extension?

Comment: I added the PHP page above. I only included the PHP. everything shows up fine on the page, it is just the .pngs that seems to be interrupted.

Comment: It is not php added to the page above. The container is calling the page and displaying it inside of the container area.

Comment: @BojanKovacevic I ran it and only got six errors and non of them are valid. the conditions that are set for the image containers are correct. w3c can not read the css to verify this.

Comment: @jrad, they was valid,some of other guys here printed them too, like the one with = missing. But true, w3c repeated error few times so number is not really correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is missing an ending div tag.  And the first div is missing an equal sign.

```
<article>
    <div class"content_container">
        <div class="content_loading_container"></div>
</article>
```

It needs to be this...

```
<article>
    <div class="content_container">
        <div class="content_loading_container"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

That's the only remaining syntax error that I can see.

Now you say ur adding these php pages and when you do, the site goes to crap.  How does it go to crap?

Comment: Sorry my page didnt refresh before I posted the last remark. On my finished page I have the right </div> in place. The png files no longer obey the css webkit transform rules. I did check the HTML and everything else is working just this one thing?

Comment: Could it be the above syntax problems causing the CSS Styles to not be selecting properly?

Comment: @Dave That's what I'm thinking the issue is.  Simply adding some .php files won't bug out CSS.

Comment: It wasnt the php files that were the issue it was in the CSS file still looking for the html in the rule I had set earlier. My bad.

Comment: @jrad so you think you've located the issue then?

Comment: Yep I got it working. Thanks for the help. Im going to accept your answer since you took the time to help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate it, watch yourself for those syntax errors.  Just one can blow up everything. ;)